# How do I go about improving my game performance on eOS?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, steam, games

So I just switched over from Windows 10 to eOS and I'm absolutely loving it so far, but one thing that's bothering me is the game performance. I play tons of Rocket League and it ran perfectly on Windows on maxed out settings but it barely runs at all on eOS. I am using the native Steam app and I have updated my drivers (I think, I updated them from the AppCentre).

I'm a Linux noob, so any help or suggestions at all would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Edit: I am running eOS on my desktop PC, my GPU is a GeForce 1050, I have 8GB RAM, my CPU is an Intel quad-core i5-7400 @ 3.00 GHz, and I have a 2TB hard-drive (but will be updating to a 1TB SSD soon)

Comment: When it comes to drivers, it is good practice to specify as much detailed information as possible related to your hardware. So please edit your question and include anything you might find relevant (video card especially, laptop make and model of applicable...)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have edited to specify

Comment: Thanks! Did you install the nvidia drivers for your card from AppCenter? To verify, open Applications and look for a nvidia settings app.

Comment: if you want install proprietary driver from nvidia website i can give u some advices, but tell us if you already installed appcenter driver.

Answer (score 1):

The Intel graphics card (integrated in your CPU) is most likely enabled by default instead of the nvidia card. Even after installing the appropriate nvidia drivers, you'll have to tell the OS to switch to the more powerful card before using graphics intensive applications.

So, after installing the nvidia driver (from the AppCenter or by using the `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` command), open the nVidia Settings app and in the Profiles section select nVidia. Type your password and reboot. After the reboot completes (hopefully without encountering the dreaded black-screen), open the nVidia Settings app again and, if all went well, you'd be presented with a whole new interface populated with details related to you nVidia card. This means the driver is successfully installed and loaded, and all that it's left to do now is to run your game and verify the performance.

You can also try disabling the Intel integrated graphics in your computer's BIOS, but the instructions on that are highly dependant on your computer's motherboard.